# RegEx inner content

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript, I'm looking to pinpoint text that's inside two other strings WITHOUT including those strings. For example:

input: `ONE example TWO`

regular expression: `(?=ONE).+(?=TWO)`

matches: `ONE example`

I want: `example`

I'm really surprised that the question mark (which is supposed just include that string in the query but not the result) works on the end of the string, but not on the start.

Comment: `(?=ONE)` matches the **position** and `.+` matches everything from that position on, including `ONE`. Just don't use a lookahead but a capture group for the text in between.

Answer (score 1):

Ah-ha! I figured it out.

for example, here's how to get text inside parenthesis without the parenthesis

```
(?<=\().+(?=\))
```

Here's a nice reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Part of my confusion was javascript's fault. It evidently doesn't support "lookbehinds" natively. I found this workaround though:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Comment: This is why you should specify the regexp engine you are using.

Comment: Specifying "javascript" is not enough?

Comment: Javascript was *not* specified. The post was edited after the fact. Check the edit history, if you don't believe me.

Comment: Oh! Thank you Trevor Senior whoever you are. :) And thank you too, Devin. I see how that happened now. (It's kind of trippy having your words edited by someone else! wow.)

Answer (score 0):

(I use Python's `re` module to show the examples -- exactly how to do this depends on your regexp implementation [some don't have groups, for example -- or backreferences])

---

Use a backwards assertion, not a forward assertion, for the first assertion.

```
>>> re.search(r"(?<=ONE).+(?=TWO)", "ONE x a b TWO").group()
' x a b '
```

The problem is that the zero width assertion `(?=ONE)` matches the text "ONE", but doesn't "consume" it -- i.e. it just checks that it's there, but leaves the string as-is. Then the `.+` starts reading text, and *does* consume it.

Backwards assertions don't look ahead, they look behind, so `.+` doesn't get run until whatever is *behind* it is "ONE".

---

It is probably better not to bother with these at all, but use groups. Consider:

```
>>> re.search(r"ONE(.+)TWO", "ONE x a b TWO").group(1)
' x a b '
```